# Find $v \times w$, where $v$ and $w$ are vectors of length $3$ in the $xz$-plane, and $\theta=\pi/6$ (angle between $v$ and $w$).

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's what I have:

$$(3)(3)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)n = v \times w$$
$$4.5n = v \times w$$

What is n?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts

Comment: ? what does this mean

Comment: @lulu I included that I've done (3)(3)sin(pi/6)n = v xx w
and 4.5 n = v xx w

Comment: Ok, you multiplied $9\times \frac 12$ successfully, but what about $\vec n$?  You are told the plane $\vec v, \vec w$ span, so what can you say about $\vec n$?

Comment: i can say that n is orthogonal to the xz plane, but I don't know what n does or what it is

Comment: Ok, well what is   $|\vec v\times \vec w|$?  What do vectors orthogonal to the $xz$ plane look like?

Comment: is it $$4.5 \langle 0, 1, 0 \rangle$$ because the unit vector normal to xz plane is y=0?

Comment: Well, that is indeed $\vec v\times \vec w$, which would make $\vec n=(0,1,0)$.  But, be careful....how do you know we don't have $\vec n=(0,-1,0)$?

Comment: Should say, you don't mean "the unit vector normal to $xz-$plane is $y=0$".  Writing $y=0$ defines the $xz-$plane, not the unit normal.

Comment: got it, 1) check right hand rule and 2) y=0 is xz plane and <0,1,0> is normal to it

Comment: There you go!  That looks like a complete answer.